# Firebase functions change fileName for uploaded file in storage

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Is there a way to change the fileName of an image with Firebase functions, without downloading and uploading it again?

I am using the onChange Listener to catch the actual upload, and I get all the data I need about the uploaded file, but I can't change any information without downloading it.

My current code:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const path = require('path');

exports.addTimeStamp = functions.storage.object().onChange(event => {
const object = event.data; // The Storage bucket that contains the file.
const filePath = object.name; // File path in the bucket.
const contentType = object.contentType; // File content type.
const resourceState = object.resourceState; // The resourceState is 'exists' or 'not_exists' (for file/folder deletions).
const metageneration = object.metageneration; // Number of times metadata has been generated. New objects have a value of 1.

// Exit if this is triggered on a file that is not an image.
if (!contentType.startsWith('image/')) {
    console.log('This is not an image.');
    return;
}

if (!filePath.startsWith('deliveryNote/')) {
    console.log('This is not a delivery note.');
    return;
}

// Get the file name.
const fileName = path.basename(filePath);
console.log('filename: ' + fileName);
// Exit if the image is already a thumbnail.
if (fileName.startsWith('note_')) {
    console.log('Already modified');
    return;
}

// Exit if this is a move or deletion event.
if (resourceState === 'not_exists') {
    console.log('This is a deletion event.');
    return;
}

// Exit if file exists but is not new and is only being triggered
// because of a metadata change.
if (resourceState === 'exists' && metageneration > 1) {
    console.log('This is a metadata change event.');
    return;
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Added folowing code thx to Doug Stevenson
const bucket = gcs.bucket(object.bucket);
var file = bucket.file(filePath);
console.log('filepath: ' + filePath);
console.log('filename: ' + fileName);
const dirname = path.dirname(filePath);
file.move(dirname + '/' + 'note_' + fileName, function(err, destinationFile, apiResponse) {
});
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To interact with files in a storage bucket, you can use the [Google Cloud Storage Node SDK](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-node#cloud-storage-ga).  Use it to obtain a File object that represents the file that changed, and use its [move](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/renaming-copying-moving-objects) method to change its name.

Comment: Can I use the Cloud storage with my Spark plan?
And it looks like the move method would do the same like above, creating a new file, deleting the old one.

Comment: It will just change the name and/or path in storage as you specify.  It won't be downloaded locally.

The limits of the Spark plan are documented here: https://firebase.google.com/pricing/